# select data record in table sqlite ios return with only one object

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

i have an problem when i select usernames the return is only one object and the table contain all of usernames how to solve this i try to select by database manager and i find that query sql statment is right

```
 - (NSMutableArray*) FindAccounts
    {
    ///database
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths; 
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];  
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"TRIAL.sqlite"]];
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT USERNAME,TYPE FROM CONTNEW"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
    NSString *USERS = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)     sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
    [resultArray addObject:USERS];
    return resultArray;
    }
    else{
    NSLog(@"Not found");
    return nil;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    }
    return nil;
    }
```

Comment: Why?  because you aren't looping.

Comment: how can i make looping for this ? thanks

Comment: Using a `while` statement instead of an `if` statement.  Remove those early `return` statements as well as you have resource leaks (hint: close the database).

Answer (score 2):

OK, try this (note that there is not much error reporting):

```
- (NSMutableArray*) FindAccounts
{
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TRIAL.sqlite"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    // I assume contactDB is an instance variable?
    if (!contactDB &&
        sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &contactDB) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT USERNAME,TYPE FROM CONTNEW ORDER BY USERNAME";
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, [querySQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *username = @(sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0));
            [resultArray addObject:username];
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```